# MongoDB: How to find messages where its chatroom is having a phonenumber?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am having this json as my message document:

```
{"_id":"nOneDzCuhE",
 "type":"text",
 "_p_chatRoomId":"chatrooms$BSxYYyUX49",
 "chatRoomIdText":"BSxYYyUX49",
 "_p_senderId":"_User$LD0r3WkuUD"
 "message":"Hello World!"
 "senderIdText":"LD0r3WkuUD"
 "_created_at":"2018-08-29 19:52:46.678",
 "_updated_at":"2018-08-29 19:52:46.678"
}
```

And this is my chatroom document:

```
{   "_id":"mfBRNbQ0gd",
    "type":"Individuals",
    "users": [
        0: {"phone_number":"987654321","id":"7AifRl9D3T","name":"user1"},
        1: {"phone_number":"123456789","id":"qapXotisT1","name":"User2"}
    ],
    "_created_at": "2018-08-14 18:11:06.090",
    "_updated_at":"2018-08-14 18:11:06.090"
}
```

So, first I want to get the id from chatRoomIdText and use it to check if this chat room has my phone number (under users array).

In Short, I want to show all the messages where their chatroom has my phone number: for eg - 987654321.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) pipeline variant to apply the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) inside the joined collection in 3.6.

Assuming join is on `chatRoomIdText` & `_id` something like should work for you.

```
db.message.aggregate([      
   {"$lookup":{
      "from":"chatroom",
      "let":{"chatRoomIdText":"$chatRoomIdText"},
      "pipeline":[
        {"$match":{
          "$expr":{
           "$and":[
              {"$eq":["$$chatRoomIdText","$_id"]},
              {"$in":["987654321","$users.phone_number"]}
             ]
           }
        }}
      ],
      "as":"lookup-results"
    }},
    {"$match":{"lookup-results.0":{"$exists":true}}},
    {"$project":{"lookup-results":0}}
])
```